# How to observe top and bottom of element with intersection observer

Tags: javascript, intersection-observer

Currently my observer is only logging the entry/ exit point as the top of the element inside the viewport. How do I watch for the entry/exit of the whole element / elements bottom

```
this.observer = new IntersectionObserver(
    (entries) => {
      entries.forEach((entry) => {
        if (entry.isIntersecting) {
          console.log("Enter");
          return;
        }
        console.log("Leave");
      });
    },
    {
      rootMargin: "0px 0px 0px",
      root: null,
      threshold: 0,
    }
  );
```

Comment: Change the value of `threshold` to `1`.